# How to pass flask return value as a variable for java script function

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have written an app in flask which return list of values to html page and that values I passed to a variable in HTML to call java script function.

I tried to execute below code but it showing an error message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'jsonfile' is undefined 

File "C:\NGConf-Explorer\myproject\templates\index.html", line 27, in top-level template code
JSONTREEVIEWER.processJSONTree('{{ url_for('static', filename=[jsonfile[0]])}}','0');
File "C:\NGConf-Explorer\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 411, in getitem
return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'jsonfile' is undefined
```

FLASK code:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        # Open a file
        #path= r"C:\NGConf-Explorer\myproject\yang\\"
        #dirs = os.listdir(path)
        filename = []
        dirs = ['Pyang_output.json2', 'Pyang_output.json3']
        for file in dirs:
            #filename.append(file).as_uri()
            #print(filename)
            filename.append(file)
        return render_template('index.html',filename=filename)
```

HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    JSONTREEVIEWER.init();
    file = {{filename|tojson}}; 
    var i;
     for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) { 
             JSONTREEVIEWER.processJSONTree('{{ url_for('static', 
              filename=file[0])}}','0');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're confusing template expansion time with JavaScript execution time. In

```
$(function(){
    JSONTREEVIEWER.init();
    jsonfile = {{filename|tojson}};
    console.log(jsonfile[0])
    JSONTREEVIEWER.processJSONTree('{{ url_for('static', filename=jsonfile[0])}}','0');
```

The template is provided with `filename` (which is a list of names), but not with `jsonfile`, which is a name that JavaScript will see once the expanded template is delivered to the browser and JavaScript executes this fragment.

But before that can happen, Jinja2 attempts to expand `url_for()`, which requires that it be provided with a `jsonfile` binding. Perhaps you meant to do something like

```
JSONTREEVIEWER.processJSONTree('{{ url_for('static', filename=filename[0])}}','0');
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working if I pass filename variable as filename[0]. But if Use code as below it's not working.                                           
file = {{filename|tojson}};
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            JSONTREEVIEWER.processJSONTree('{{ url_for('static', filename=filename[0])}}','0');
        }

Comment: Could you please help me here

Comment: Assuming the json expands as expected (which you can confirm by viewing the source of the page in the browser), a few well-placed `console.log()` calls in your JS should show you what's going on. You'll need to open up your browsers development tools to get a console. How to do that depends on what browser you're using.